# IIS log timestap timezone

Tags: python, datetime, iis

I have some IIS(Internet Information Service) logs that I need to process, something like the Apache web log if you are a Linux server guy.

The web logs starts with:

```
49.76.xx.xx - - [01/Jun/2015:00:01:08 -0500] "GET...
```

And I am curious about the timestamp, `[01/Jun/2015:00:01:08 -0500]`, what does 0500 mean in this scenario? is it something like the timezone or offset based on [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) python documentation?

This is what I have done so far but it doesn't work:

```
from datetime import datetime
text = "01/Jun/2015:00:01:08 +0500"
print datetime.strptime(text, '%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z')
```

And here is the error message.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-e243ceb157eb> in <module>()
      1 from datetime import datetime
      2 text = "01/Jun/2015:00:01:08 +0500"
----> 3 print datetime.strptime(text, '%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z')

/opt/local/anaconda/lib/python2.7/_strptime.pyc in _strptime(data_string, format)
    315                 del err
    316                 raise ValueError("'%s' is a bad directive in format '%s'" %
--> 317                                     (bad_directive, format))
    318             # IndexError only occurs when the format string is "%"
    319             except IndexError:

ValueError: 'z' is a bad directive in format '%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z'
```

Comment: `-0500` is a *time zone offset*, which means that this specific local time was 5 hours behind UTC.   Do not confuse *offset* with *time zone*, as many time zones change their offsets for daylight saving time and other anomalies.  Also, be careful - you show `-0500` in one case, and `+0500` in another.  Those are 10 hours apart from each other.

Answer (score 0):

`%z` represents the timezone..you cannot use `%z` with `.strptime()` .. you might consider using `pytz` module for timezone